# Safari inserts "localhost" in URLs with three slashes after the scheme

Tags: safari, url

Safari seems to be the only browser that differently handles URL's that have three slashes after the scheme.

For example typing https:///google.com in the address bar results in the URL being converted to https://google.com by all browsers I tried (Edge, Firefox, Opera, Tor), excepting for Safari, which converts the URL to https://localhost/google.com.

The conversion also happens when receiving a HTTP redirect (301 or 302) with a "malformed" URL, but doesn't happen when clicking on a link, in that case Safari is consistent with the other browsers.

Does somebody know why is that? And who's correct - Safari inserting `localhost`, or the other browsers stripping out the third slash?

Comment: Where are you finding URLs for webpages with three slashes?

Comment: @benwiggy I stumbled upon a buggy web app that was sending redirects to urls with three slashes, and coincidently I was using mobile safari at that time, otherwise the behaviour would've gone unnoticed.

Comment: You are facing this only when typed directly in the address bar, right? For me (as per the URL specs), the anchor in your question correctly leads to `https://google.com`. What happens in the address bar is not specced though, so nobody is wrong.

Comment: @Kaiido the behaviour happens when directly typing and when receiving a redirect (301/302) from a server. Indeed, clicking on a link has the same behaviour on Safari as on the other browsers.

Comment: Ah then this is a Safari bug. Per the [Fetch specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-fetch) they should [parse](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-parser) the \`Location\` header, and this parser does ignore several `/` after `protocol://`, just like they do with `<a href="url">`. You may want to [add an issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/) to their tracker. If it helps, I made a repro-case [here](https://evergreen-befitting-venus.glitch.me/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when the text is entered in the address bar of the browser is not tied by any specs yet, so for this situation there is no "wrong" or "correct" behavior.

However, for redirects sent by the server in response to a fetch request, the [Fetch standards](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org) rule, and [these standards](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-fetch)(§8.2 - "follow") [ask](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-location-url) that the `Location` header in the response be parsed through the URL standards [URL-parser](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-parser) algorithm.

This algorithm when it will encounter the third `/` in the [special authority ignore slashes state](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-authority-ignore-slashes-state) will emit a [validation error](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#validation-error), but won't leave this step until all subsequent `/` are found (and thus ignored).

So the result of parsing an input such as `https:///////example.com` should be

```
protocol: "https:"
host: "example.com"
path: "/"
```

I.E, the multiple `/` characters after `https:` are ignored.

And even Safari agrees on that in other places, like in HTML's `<a href>`, as can be seen from the links in OP.

That they don't follow this rule for fetch redirects is a bug, and as such, you may want to report it to their [bug-tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/).

Answer (score 5):

@AlvarPaalberg's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437067/237) gives an earlier view

There are later RFCs that I think add to this.

The one I found is [RFC7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230) defining the http protocol. This includes

> A sender MUST NOT generate an "http" URI with an empty host
> identifier.  A recipient that processes such a URI reference MUST
> reject it as invalid.

Also [RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

> If the URI scheme defines a default for host, then that default
> applies when the host subcomponent is undefined or when the
> registered name is empty (zero length).  For example, the "file" URI
> scheme is defined so that no authority, an empty host, and
> "localhost" all mean the end-user's machine, whereas the "http"
> scheme considers a missing authority or empty host invalid.

From that I think all the browsers are incorrect. They should be rejecting the URL as invalid. Now browsers in general have never liked reporting errors for invalid html or anything else so they decide what they think the user typed and use that instead.

Safari has chosen a different view to others. (It has used the rule for the file: scheme - which I guess is due to Safari developers being more integrated withe the OS developers than is the case for other browsers. macOS system APIs us file URLs for most file operations)

Comment: Why would the protocol -- which governs how a browser should communicate with a server -- dictate how the UI/UX -- the interaction between browser and user -- works?

Comment: Becaus RFC7230 says at the top "This document provides an overview of HTTP architecture and  its associated terminology, defines the "http" and "https" Uniform    Resource Identifier (URI) scheme" and the slashes are part of the scheme.

Comment: Yes, and? That is the protocol the browser uses to talk to other programs. The browser should adhere to it when doing that. But the interaction with the user happens on a different OSI level. Hell, there are many web clients out there which completely hide the URI from the user and you can't even type any in. You assume the address bar of the browser *must* be an URI, that is definitely wrong. In chrome, can even type in math equations there and get a result, or a google query, or wikipedia query.

Comment: The RFC simply doesn't apply to that field. As long as the browser correctly uses the protocol behind the curtain, there is no RFC violation. Assuming a technical specification is good UX is bad, that is why most browsers have an added layer of abstraction on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

One can try to give answer to the question `why?` but not `who is correct?`

---

[RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738):

The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a
particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes,
does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the
Internet.

A file URL takes the form:

```
    file://<host>/<path>
```

/../ As a special case,  can be the string "localhost" **or the empty
string;** this is interpreted as `the machine from which the URL is
being interpreted'.

---

So it appears that Safari considers three slashes as file URL scheme special case (empty string) and replaces empty string between second and third slash with 'localhost'. Other browsers consider it as user entered one slash too much and actually want to access internet resource so they 'autocorrect' it.

Comment: If that's the case, seems it's a bug in Safari, as the scheme is `https`, not `file`, in order for Safari to consider the url as a file url.

Comment: @Cristik - from another hand, there is no internet resource URL scheme with  three slashes. So one can claim that this is bug if I enter three slashes and are taken to the internet by my browser. Shouldn't error to be raised? `file://` is request to local file, `http://` is request to file somewhere (including local filesystem) using HTTP protocol. Three slashes are interpreted as request to access local filesystem. I don't pretend to be expert in this area and I have not read all the RFC-s so my interpretation is as good as anybody elses.